# Один токен работает для всех аккаунтов django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, authenticationtoken

Создал систему авторизации через токен, пользователь вводит емайл и пароль, возвращается токен, далее этот токен идет в заголовке всех остальных запросов. Все работает, но заметил что один токен подходит для всех аккаунтов. То есть, можно ввести любые email и пароль, но если прикреплен какой-нибудь из существующих токенов, то запрос пройдет. Разве это нормально? Один токен должен работать только с одним аккаунтом. Что я сделал не так? Permission class на всех view стоит IsAuthenticated.

views.py (тут функция просто для теста, возвращает список всех аккаунтов)

```py
class AccountLoginTest(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        acc = Account.objects.all()
        return acc
```

serializers.py (сериалайзер аккаунтов)

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
            required=True,
            validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
            )
    username = serializers.CharField(
            validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
            )
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=7, write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = Account.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'],
             validated_data['password'])
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('account/testGet/', views.AccountLoginTest.as_view()),
]
```

settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'account',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
      'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', ),
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.Account'

ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
```

Comment: Вы написали самостоятельную систему авторизации? Если я правильно понял... Тут вопрос в реализации. А ее никак не получится прокомментировать не видя исходного кода

Comment: @virvaldium отредактировал, добавил код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну смотрите, что я вижу...У вас установлена Django и в качестве расширений используется DjangoRestFraemwork
В качестве средства аутентифкации вы указали:
`rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication`
Этот модуль делает только проверку наличия токена + проверку того, что у этого токена не истек срок годности.
То есть ваш вопрос: 
`То есть, можно ввести любые email и пароль, но если прикреплен какой-нибудь из существующих токенов, то запрос пройдет. Разве это нормально?`
в данной ситуации несколько не уместен. Посколько `TokenAuthentication` проверил, что токен есть и этот токен еще валиден. И все... Больше он ничего не делает. 
А то что этот токен прикреплен к другой учетной записи, так это проблема не аутентификации, а авторизации.

По факту, ваша ситуация выглядит таким образом: токен это как пропуск, тот у кого пропуск может проходить на предприятие. Охранник стоящий на входе проверяет толлько наличие пропуска, но он не сверяет фотографии тех кому был выдан этот пропуск. Предпологается, что пропуском пользуется только его владелец. А вы взяли отдали свой пропуск другому человек - соответвенно он прошел на предприятие без проблем

Comment: Понял вас, спасибо. Получается, нужно делать какие-нибудь дополнительные проверки на связь аккаунта и конкретного токена?

Comment: эм... не думаю.. Предпологается, что токен есть только у владельца. Если клиент предоставляет токен для пользователя user1, то скорее всего это и есть user1. Собственно для этого и нужен токен, если вы каждый раз просите пользователя ввести логин и пароль, то смысл в токене пропадает

Comment: ясно. Тогда схема, получается, такая: пользователь отправляет логин и пароль, если они верны то возвращается токен, который используется для последующих обращений?

Comment: Да, верно. Но при этом стоит помнить, что можно ли пользователю делать запрос по данному url или нет - это реализуется отдельно силами программиста

Comment: все понял. Благодарю за ответ )